# Restrict tomcat access by ip

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat

I want to restrict access to a webapp running on a tomcat server by ip address.
Found out that I would have to use `org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve` and set it in a tomcat `context.xml`

But within my tomcat folder I have 4 of it:

```
\conf
\backup
\webapps\host-manager\META-INF
webapps\manager\META-INF
```

Where to I have to place my Rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to choose `context.xml` which is under `TOMCAT_HOME/conf/` if you want to apply this restriction to all webapps running on your tomcat.

Choose `yourapp/META-INF/context.xml` if you want to keep it only for application.
If the web application is packaged as a WAR then `/META-INF/context.xml` will be copied to `$TOMCAT_HOME/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/` and renamed to match the application's context path.

`webapps\manager\META-INF` => if you add restriction here, your `tomcat manager` will be restricted i.e. `tomcat administration`.

Comment: `<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteHostValve" allow="127\.0\.0\.1"/>` having this I can even not access my webapp from localhost where it is deployed. What is wrong?

Comment: Your first sentence should refer to server.xml.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the configuration for [RemoteAddressFilter](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/valve.html#Remote_Address_Filter)
You can add the `Valve` to `%CATALINA_HOME%\conf\server.xml`
But if you need to filter by IPs I would recommend you use the firewall instead. That is what it is supposed to do in the first place

Answer (score 1):

it should be inside YOUR_WEBAPP/META-INF/context.xml